# Roslyn: How to get the ITypeSymbol associated with an identifier?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I'm attempting to write a Roslyn analyzer to detect usages of `Enumerable.Count()` being called on arrays. Here is the relevant code in my analyzer:

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeInvocationExpression, SyntaxKind.InvocationExpression);
}

private static void AnalyzeInvocationExpression(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var invocation = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)context.Node;
    var memberAccess = invocation.Expression as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;
    if (!memberAccess.IsKind(SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression))
    {
        return;
    }

    Debug.Assert(memberAccess != null);
    var ident = memberAccess.Name.Identifier;
    // Check whether the method is Count() and there is no parameter list before we try to use the Symbol APIs.
    if (ident.ToString() != nameof(Enumerable.Count))
    {
        return;
    }

    var arguments = invocation.ArgumentList.Arguments;
    if (arguments.Count > 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Make sure that the subject is an array.
    var subject = memberAccess.Expression;
    var subjectSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(subject).Symbol;
    if (subjectSymbol == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    // ???
}
```

I'm stuck trying to determine whether the object that `Count()` is being invoked on is an array. I scanned the API a bit and I see there is an `ILocalSymbol` with a `Type` property, and also an `IFieldSymbol` with a `Type` property that will both presumably get you the type of the object. However, I don't know whether the object I'm analyzing is a local/field/result of a method call/etc, so I would expect `IFieldSymbol` and `ILocalSymbol` to e.g. share some common base interface, say `IVariableSymbol`, that offers you the `Type` without having to know all the possible places the variable could have come from. However, it seems both interfaces derive directly from `ISymbol`.

Is the best solution just to do something like this?

```
internal static class SymbolUtilities
{
    public static ITypeSymbol GetType(ISymbol symbol)
    {
        if (symbol is IFieldSymbol)
        {
            return ((IFieldSymbol)symbol).Type;
        }

        if (symbol is ILocalSymbol)
        {
            return ((ILocalSymbol)symbol).Type;
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the information about the type, using the method `GetTypeInfo` of the `SemanticModel` class:

```
ITypeSymbol subjectType = context.SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(subject).Type;
```

You will find more details about it in the article

"[Introduction to Roslyn and its use in program development](https://medium.com/@CPP_Coder/introduction-to-roslyn-and-its-use-in-program-development-bce2043fc45d#.2k8fxxg3p)"